# Does "His eyes fell shut" make sense?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, writing, literature

This is something I've been writing for a while, but I know that I tend to keep writing things from my tween years that may not make sense.

Have you ever read a sentence like "his eyes fell shut" or maybe "his eyelids fell shut"? To me, it's kind of like writing "the door swung open"... His eyes fell shut. Hmmm.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **eyes fall shut** is a perfectly acceptable expression, [used by many a writers to spruce up their prose](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eyes%20fall%20shut%22&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilnP2KwdfcAhWSbysKHdqGDUUQ_AUIDigA&biw=1366&bih=654). Feel free to use it.

One peculiarity I found is that **fall shut** seems to elude every single reputable dictionary I could get my hands on. This leads me to the - admittedly rash - conclusion that **fall shut** is used exclusively with **eyes**, for some strange reason. Googling did not produce any pertinent results, so I'm curious as to why this is the case. Might be a potential topic for  a future question.

Comment: It's used for more than just eyes. Here, used in the literal sense: "Can a roof access hatch _fall shut_?":  https://roofaccesshatches.co.uk/faq/about-the-products/can-a-roof-access-hatch-fall-shut

Comment: I never knew about the ability to search within a "Books" tab on Google before. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard it used in this way, "His eyes fell shut", but it *does* sound rather poetic, if that's what you're going for in this instance, and the meaning would come across to most native speakers.